# Display error with Github vs Browsersync

Tags: jquery, html, css, github

I've created a test site, that essentially shows the London underground with an interactive map. You can click at different points, and info about them will come up. It uses jQuery, CSS and HTML and I've been working with browsersync to track my work progress.

Functionally, it displays fine whilst using browser sync, but when displayed on Github - it seems that something is missing - many items aren't styled, or animations do not occur in the correct way.

[Link to the repository on Git](https://github.com/Turnerskizzle/TFLOne)
[The site, as it is displayed online](https://turnerskizzle.github.io/TFLOne/)

Is there a basic step I'm missing? 
Thanks in advance! 
Lloyd

Comment: probably you have not properly copied all prerequisites. Open the browser console and see if errors appear.

Comment: Seems the `styles.css` is returning 404 Not Found.

Comment: The down voting is harsh, but generally questions are better received on SO if they are focused on a single problem. That way later it can help other people. Open ended questions about specific apps are not usually given as much attention. Tough lesson to learn when you are learning though. Don't let it dishearten you.

Comment: Okay - it's all a learning experience, thank you though!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer once the question is resolved. Helps people looking through SO to know what needs attention and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code. Instead of this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/styles.css">
```

it should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
```

As I have already made a pull request for changes. Review it and feel free to merge it.

Comment: Thanks for the pull request - as said above, seems like such a simple thing - not a mistake I'll make again!

Comment: Glad to hear you, it get fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a part of the route missing for the stylesheet.

The scripts file has a URL: https://turnerskizzle.github.io/TFLOne/scripts/scripts.js

So the URL for the css should be: https://turnerskizzle.github.io/TFLOne/stylesheets/styles.css at the moment it is https://turnerskizzle.github.io/stylesheets/styles.css

You can fix this by removing the leading slash from the URL in your `index.html`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css">
```

As his will make the path relative to the current page which is served from `https://turnerskizzle.github.io/TFLOne/` (which is the index file) and not an absolute route from the domain `https://turnerskizzle.github.io`. Which is what the leading `/` means in a URL.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - seems like such a simple fix! The url provided through the Git settings is https://turnerskizzle.github.io/TFL/ - which still doesn't work. based off of what you've said with the styles.css at the end, I tried https://turnerskizzle.github.io/TFL/index.html, which works. Will I always have to add the html extension to the URL's provided by Git?

Comment: If you are serving a specific file you will need to add the `.{whatever}`, but if there is some server routing going on in the background (which there no doubt is with github pages) you might not. Here github knows that you have a `index.html` and will serve that from the `/TFL` route. You might still need to be careful with the absolute vs relative paths though. Neat app btw, looks cool.